# boost::assign for a set not working with +=

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use Boost::assign and the operator += to initialize a static set that I am planning to use later. I followed the steps specified in this [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#operator+=). The code is split across three files

```
/*Assign.hpp*/
#ifndef __SAMPLE_CLASS__
#define __SAMPLE_CLASS__

#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <boost/assign/std/set.hpp>

class SampleClass
{
    public:
        SampleClass();
        ~SampleClass();

        typedef std::set<int> SET_TYPE;

        static const SET_TYPE my_set1;
        static const SET_TYPE my_set2;
};

#endif

/*Assign.cpp*/
#include "assign.hpp"

using namespace boost::assign;

const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set1 += 1,2,3;
const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set2 += 4,5,6;

SampleClass::SampleClass()
{

}

SampleClass::~SampleClass()
{

}

/*main.cpp*/
#include "assign.hpp"                    

int main()
{
    SampleClass sobj;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following compilation error when I issue the following command

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include main.cpp assign.cpp
```

Error snippet

```
assign.cpp:6:50: error: invalid '+=' at end of declaration; did you mean '='?
const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set1 += 1,2,3;
                                             ^~
                                             =
assign.cpp:6:42: error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'const SampleClass::SET_TYPE' (aka 'const set<int>')
const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set1 += 1,2,3;
                                     ^          ~
assign.cpp:6:55: error: expected unqualified-id
const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set1 += 1,2,3;
                                                  ^
assign.cpp:6:55: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set1 += 1,2,3;

...
```

Is there something wrong in the way I am trying to initialize my static set or my usage of the += operator here?

Comment: You can't initialize something by only using `+=` on it. You have to give it some value.

Comment: @chris The documentation on Boost::assign says that the operator += has been overloaded to provide that functionality. The example that they are using is as follows - values += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; where values is a vector of int

Comment: I'm not arguing that you can use `+=` to do that, but you can't use it to initialize something. It's like doing `int i += 2;`

Comment: @rgk: The example is using `+=` to modify an existing container, not to initialise a new one. That's the only way you can use it.

Comment: @chris Thanks. Went through the documentation again and the function that I wanted was a list_of and not the +=

Comment: @rgk, Ah, yes, I remember that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `+=` in an initialization statement.

Comment: The function I need is a list_of() rather than the += operator. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like this if your compiler supports c++11:

```
const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set1 = {1,2,3};
const SampleClass::SET_TYPE SampleClass::my_set2 = {4,5,6};
```

Comment: I haven't tried this as my compiler is not C++11 compliant